# Why is `uint32_t` typedeffed to `unsigned long` on arm-none-eabi GCC, and how to change it?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` 7.4 to compile a "bare-metal" program for an ARM Cortex-M4 based microcontroller (specifically, the EFM32WG940 but this should be irrelevant to the question).

As far as I see, `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long int)` alongside with their unsigned counterparts are both `4`. You actually have to type `long long int` to get a 64-bit integer (or `int64_t`), so `long int` seems to be entirely superfluous.

In this environment, why is the `__UINT32_TYPE__` [predefined macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) defined to `long unsigned int`?

Is there a way to change `uint32_t` to be `unsigned int` instead?

Normally this wouldn't bother me, but it causes `printf` to give me a hard time because of `-Wformat`. Consider something like: `printf("hello %u\n", i);` (assuming `i` is `uint32_t`)
which gives me a warning because `%u` expects `unsigned` but `uint32_t` is `unsigned long`. Obviously I can change it to `%lu` but then the same code will give me a warning when compiled on x86.

**EDIT:**

Yes, one way to silence `-Wformat` is to use the [format macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants) from `inttypes.h` like this: `printf("hello %" PRIu32, i);` which while doesn't actually answer my question, would be amost OK if the code weren't so ugly, and some static analyzers didn't have problems with it.

Instead of hacking all my printf calls, I'd like to understand why `uint32_t` needs to be `unsigned long int` instead of `unsigned int` on this platform, and how to change that.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants - There's a standard way to print them, the implementation must take care of that as well

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, that's one way to go about it, but it results in some very very ugly code.

Comment: @StoryTeller's is the *right* way to do it.  There is no conforming way to change a type declaration once made.  There is also no conforming way to provide your own declaration of an identifier specified by the standard, for the use the standard specifies for it.  If you must use the explicit-width types, then the format macros go along with them.

Comment: Among your alternatives are (1) to use your knowledge of the actual underlying type in your particular implementation to write format strings for that type, and (2) to use the standard type of your choice (e.g. `unsigned int`) directly.  These of course have portability issues, but that may not be important for your purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger While I appreciate your comment about the format strings, I would still welcome an answer to the actual question, ie. why is long only 32-bit here, and why is uint32_t typedeffed to unsigned long instead of unsigned.

Comment: @StoryTeller most of the bare metal printf implementations do not implement those formats for the code size reasons. Even float printfing has to be impicity allowed by the programmer. This comment in the bsare metal environment is useless.

Comment: @P__J__ - Then downvote it.

Comment: Only the GCC devs who made the decision can answer the "why" part of the question definitively, @Venemo.  The rest of us can only speculate.  But do note that some implementations have 16-bit `int`s, and on those `unsigned int` would not meet the criteria for `uint32_t`.  Those implementations include GCC on some architectures, where `unsigned long` would be correct, but `unsigned int` would not.

Comment: What formats don't "bare metal implementations" provide, @P__J__?  Note that we're talking about one of `"%lu"` and `"%u"`.  The use of an appropriate macro to choose the right one of those has no code-size implication.  Of course, standalone implementations don't need to provide a conforming standard library (or any standard library at all), but it seems unlikely that any implementation would provide `printf()`, but not the formats for the types it supports.

Comment: @JohnBollinger gcc devs do not define it this way. The problem is the headers provided by the chip manufacturer.

Comment: They don't define it *what* way, @P__J__?  We're talking about standard features of the language, and GCC / glibc *does* conform in this area.

Comment: 1) why are you using printf() with bare-metal?  Its about the most system intense C function there is.  and baremetal is without a system.  2) the compiler authors choose how to map the uint32_t type aliases into the real variable types used by the compiler/language.  If they want to choose unsigned long for 32 bit then that is how it goes, roll with it.  Or choose to use the real variable types yourself directly and accept portability issues, or have a way to deal with them.   the toolchain including stdint.h is within your control you are free to modify it.

Comment: If using system calls in bare metal there is no assumption of portability, actually with baremetal there is no assumption of portability so you need to be the master of your tools.  Since you need to control the linker which is often through a linker script as well as the bootstrap that it is often married to, so you are already bound to a toolchain.  If you dont control the toolchain then you are gambling anyway.  In any case its a gamble.  IMO take control of the toolchain...

Comment: From time to time you will find the cross compiler uses the wrong stdint.h anyway, it uses the host not the targets.  that is if you trust one you found rather than build your own and own it...and in that case all kinds of problems occur, the wrong sizes are used here and there any code that relies on stdint.h fails, etc...

Comment: @Venemo I hit the same issue. Even worse, we use both ARM gcc and clang. Both compiler translate uint32_t into different type. (GCC to 'unsigned long' and clang to 'unsigned int'). If use %lX, clang will complain, otherwise, gcc complained. I don't have solution beside the ugly -Wno-format.

Answer (score 5):

> As far as I see, `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long int)` alongside with their
>   unsigned counterparts are both 4. You actually have to type `long long int` to get
>   a 64-bit integer (or `int64_t`), so `long int` seems to be
>   entirely superfluous.

The C language does not specify the exact widths of the standard integer types.  Rather, it specifies the minimum range of values that each must represent.  This allows C to be written in a natural way for targets of differing architecture.  In particular, a conforming implementation may provide `int`s with as few as 15 value bits, whereas `long int` must have at least 31, and `long long int` must have at least 63.  The signed integer types also have a sign bit, and the unsigned counterparts one additional value bit.  (Any of these may also have padding bits, though that's uncommon.)  So no, `long int` is not superfluous, at least not in a semantic sense.

> In this environment, why is the `__UINT32_TYPE__` predefined macro
>   defined to `long unsigned int`?

First off, `__UINT32_TYPE__` is a glibc implementation detail.  Thus, the only reasonable answer to that question as posed is "because `unsigned long int` is the type chosen for `uint32_t`."  But I take you to in fact be asking why that type was chosen in the first place.  I cannot speak definitively to reasons for the GCC / glibc developers' decisions here, but I think I would have made the same choice in their place, where they are trying to support a wide variety of architectures.

Because `long int` and `unsigned long int` are guaranteed to have at least 31 and 32 value bits, respectively (and `int` and `unsigned int` are not), the long versions are natural choices for [`u`]`int32_t` on those platforms where they in fact meet its requirements (*exactly* 32 bits total, no padding bits, and the signed version implemented as two's complement).  The long versions are the only right choice for some supported architectures, and they are among the acceptable choices for most of the rest.  By choosing the long versions, glibc needs to make exceptions only for a subset of 64-bit platforms, and perhaps a few platforms with oddball integer types.

There is no requirement, and no justification for any expectation, that `int` and `unsigned int` will be the types chosen for `int32_t` and `uint32_t` when they satisfy the requirements for that, unless they are the *only* available types that satisfy the requirements.

> Is there a way to change `uint32_t` to be `unsigned int` instead?

There is no conforming way for your C code to change the definition of `uint32_t` provided by the implementation.  You could try hacking your C implementation to make the change, or you could choose an altogether different implementation, but any attempt to redefine the already-defined type produces undefined behavior (and is probably, but not necessarily, rejected by the compiler).

The standard way to deal with the type variability when using the explicit-width types with the formatted I/O functions is to use [the macros provided for that purpose](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8.1), of which you are already aware.  Alternatively, if you're satisfied that you know the applicable definitions of the types involved for all platforms of interest, then you can write the appropriate formats directly.  Or you can use the standard type of your choice directly (*e.g.* `unsigned int`) or, for `printf` but not `scanf`, cast the argument to a type matching the format.

Do not lightly dismiss the alternative of using standard types instead of the explicit-width type aliases.  The former are a smoother alternative where they are sufficient -- no need for any special headers, and smooth interoperability with all standard library functions.

> Obviously I can change it to `%lu` but then the same code will give me a
>   warning when compiled on x86.

Maybe it will, maybe it won't.  Type `unsigned long` is 32 bits wide on glibc for 32-bit x86, too.  I'm uncertain whether it's the type chosen for `int32_t` there, but it's one of the viable alternatives.  The same holds even for some 64-bit platforms, such as Win64.  For any given platform where both alternatives are viable, you're likely to find some implementations that choose one, and some that choose the other.

Comment: Your answe ris strictly theorethical - you asmited that you have no experience in the uC programming. All of the arm-gcc ports I know define alias the uint32_t to the unsigned int. Probably OPs toolchain header files have a 8bits uC background and they have defined it as `unsigned long` (on 8 bits uCs usually int is 16bits). There are no warnings on all toolchains I use: https://godbolt.org/z/2bnTz5

Comment: @P__J__ In the compiler explorer you chose "ARM GCC" which is **not** the same as `arm-none-eabi-gcc` that my question is about. Here is the same code in the correct GCC variant, and you can see the exact warning that I'm talking about. https://godbolt.org/z/8Cc_ii

Comment: @P__J__, my answer is a standards-based response to the questions actually posed: why does the implementation make the choices it does, and can they be overridden.  It accepts the implicit premise that the OP has characterized the situation accurately (which seems to be verifiable), but even if they haven't, that just makes the question hypothetical.